# Re-render React component and display new data when changing data in MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My React app is using a modal to create, update, and delete data fetched from mongodb.

This is my component structure:

index.js

- making the fetch call to retrieve the data
- passing the data as a prop to the admin component (admin component is a route)

admin component

- displaying the contents of the data on the page into a grid
- open modal component

modal component

- create/update/delete data with a form and make a fetch call

I want the admin component to update and show the created/updated/deleted data
immediately after submitting the change in the modal.

I know normally you would have the displayed data as state and then alter that to update the
component and show the new data. In my case that data is getting passed in as a prop to the admin component
from index.js which is fetching the data. I thought another potential way to update the component would be to
create an isUpdated state hook and pass into the modal and toggle its value but that didnt seem to work.

Comment: Does `index.js` have to make the fetch call? Ideally, you would keep as much logic out of `index.js` as possible and move them into respective components.

You can pass props from `admin` to `modal`, and then have `modal` update the props after API calls. Similarly to how you pass the prop, you can pass a function from parent to child which modifies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had a fairly simple solution. I was able to solve this by setting the data passed in as props to the admin component in a state hook then pass in the variable and setter function to the modal. In the modal, build a new object with the data collected from the form and use the setter function to push the new data object into the array of the hook and I got the result I wanted. Thanks to the other answerers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add real-time updates to your component, so any changes to the data will be reflected without the need of forcing your components to re-render.

You can use streams to get your updates in your database. There is a page with a good tutorial:

https://pusher.com/tutorials/mongodb-change-streams/